# How to extract values from an XML fragment using a Ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

```
"lorem <tt>text1</tt> ipsum <tt>text2</tt>dolor si amet"
```

I need to extract the text between `<tt>...</tt>` into an array, I've tried with:

```
"lorem <tt>text1</tt> ipsum <tt>text2</tt>dolor si amet".scan(/<tt>(.*)<\/tt>/)
```

but with no luck...

Comment: Great! The Cthulhu-prevention squad was hoping to enjoy a Christmas break, and now you come along! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 4):

It is so much better to use a parser, even with a tiny fragment, unless you are sure the string will never change format and you own the process from end-to-end.

That said, to meet your requirement of a regex, I'd use String.scan:

```
str = "lorem <tt>text1</tt> ipsum <tt>text2</tt>dolor si amet"

str.scan(%r{<tt>([^<]+)</tt>}).flatten # => ["text1", "text2"]
```

Just to show how simple using a parser is:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
doc.css('tt').map(&:text) # => ["text1", "text2"]
```

The benefit is flexibility and robustness.

Answer (score 2):

Try `.scan(/<tt>(.*?)<\/tt>/)`

Here `*?` is so-called 'reluctant quantifier'.

```
s = "lorem <tt>text1</tt> ipsum <tt>text2</tt>dolor si amet"
puts s.scan(/<tt>(.*?)<\/tt>/).inspect #  => [["text1"], ["text2"]]
```